# Flutter - How to implement a 'sloppy' back gesture to go back to previous screen?

Tags: user-interface, flutter

I would like to start the back gesture from anywhere on the screen, as opposed to at the very edge of the screen - just like the behavior when using Instagram on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is Cupertino page transition, 
Flutter has the documentation for it:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoPageTransition-class.html

You can also find other literature by searching the keyword I gave you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `GestureDetector` widget to capture a "horizontal drag" and then use the `onPanUpdate(details)` to find out the direction of the drag. `details` in `onPanUpdate` gives you access to a `delta` field which will give you your swipe direction.

Check out this article, it's pretty handy!
https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-deep-dive-gestures-c16203b3434f